# What word can I use for a poset with equivalences

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Often I want to define a structure on a set $S$ which is like a poset, but lacks the antisymmetry condition: i.e., one is allowed both $a\succeq b$ and $a \preceq b$ for $a, b$ different elements of my set. One way to say this is "a category structure with underlying set $S$ which is equivalent to a poset" (where pairs $a, b$ as above are simply related by an isomorphism). But this is a mouthful, and I would like a better, more canonical term for this. Does one exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called [preorders](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder). (The nLab also suggests the term "proset" but I think this is terrible; "proset" should mean a pro-object in sets.) They're the same thing as categories enriched over truth values.

Comment: Some people also say quasiorder.

Comment: I quite dislike both "pre" and "quasi" as prefixes for more general versions of things (especially when they're used to name the more fundamental concept, which I think is the case here), but of the two I prefer "pre" because it's shorter.

Comment: I agree. I'm just pointing out both are in use.

Comment: To be fair, the nLab does remark on prosets vs. pro-sets (the latter being used for pro-objects). I'm not sure that the nLab is alone in this particular naming; perhaps it's trying to be descriptive of a usage, not prescriptive in the manner of suggesting that other people use it. But I can make a pretty good guess where it comes from: it is by way of rhyming with "poset" (partially ordered set), "woset" (well-ordered set), "loset" (linearly ordered set) and "toset" (totally ordered set). [I never say "proset" myself.]

Comment: So is the pro-proset set empty?